# JQ Group_by or Unique not working for nested arrays

Tags: json, csv, jq, unique, distinct

Trying to get unique entries from nested JSON arrays.

JSON Source

```
[
{"SIR":[{"PMD":[{"MMA":[{"DN":"One","SA":"1"},{"DN":"Two","SA":"2"}]}]}]},
{"SIR":[{"PMD":[{"MMA":[{"DN":"Two","SA":"2"},{"DN":"Four","SA":"4"}]}]}]},
{"SIR":[{"PMD":[{"MMA":[{"DN":"Three","SA":"3"},{"DN":"Five","SA":"5"}]}]}]}
]
```

Filter producing non-unique results:

```
'.[].SIR.PMD.MMA 
    | [.DN, .SA]
    | @csv'
```

Current Output (CSV

```
One,1
Two,2
Two,2
Three,3
Four,4
Five,5
```

Desired Output (CSV)

```
One,1
Two,2
Three,3
Four,4
Five,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Collect the items to be filtered into an array, and use either `unique` alone to compare the whole objects, or `unique_by` on any filter combination, e.g. `.DN`):

```bash
jq -r 'map(.SIR[].PMD[].MMA[]) | unique[] | [.DN, .SA] | @csv'
```

```bash
jq -r 'map(.SIR[].PMD[].MMA[]) | unique_by(.DN)[] | [.DN, .SA] | @csv'
```

---

Note that the output will be sorted, in the first case by the whole object, in the latter by the filter provided. To achieve the numeric ordering of your sample output, use `unique_by` on either just `(.SA|tonumber)`, or first `(.SA|tonumber)` then `.DN`. The conversion to numbers only affects the sorting, not the output:

```bash
jq -r 'map(.SIR[].PMD[].MMA[]) | unique_by(.SA|tonumber)[] | [.DN, .SA] | @csv'
```

```bash
jq -r 'map(.SIR[].PMD[].MMA[]) | unique_by([(.SA|tonumber), .DN])[] | [.DN, .SA] | @csv'
```

```
"One","1"
"Two","2"
"Three","3"
"Four","4"
"Five","5"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Every other solution I could find had the map occur within the array (ie: ".SIR[].PMD[].MMA[] | map(.DN)") which didn't make any sense and didn't work.  This makes much more sense